# Optimizing an Oracle SQL Query for Faster Results

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a new table to get data from the last 7 days - from a table with millions of rows of daily data on **Oracle SQL** and 2 other tables just to get the item id and store ids. It doesn't even run anymore because it's too big. How can I write to optimize this better?

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE PARALLEL 6 as
SELECT 
        A.DATE_DT,
        B.STORE_NUM,
        C.ITEM_ID,
        A.BALANCE_ONHAND,
        A.DEMAND,
        A.PENDING_DELIVERY            
FROM TABLE.QTY A,
      TABLE.STORES B,
      TABLE.ITEMS C,
     (SELECT DATE_DT FROM DAY WHERE DATE_DT BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-6) and TRUNC(SYSDATE)) D
WHERE A.ITEM_ID = C.ITEM_ID 
      AND A.STORE_NUM = B.STORE_NUM
      AND A.DATE_DT = D.DATE_DT
order by A.DATE_DT;
```

Here are the columns in every table:

```
TABLE.QTY

A.DATE_DT,
A.ITEM_ID,
A.STORE_NUM,
A.BALANCE_ONHAND,
A.DEMAND,
A.PENDING_DELIVERY  

TABLE.STORES (the stores that I only want to see which is why it's a separate table) 
STORE_NUM

TABLE.ITEMS (the items that I only want to see which is why it's a separate table)
ITEM_ID

DAY
It's a pre-made table by Oracle with Day dates.
```

I'm open to anything. Eventually I plan to schedule this query on my alation so it creates a new table every week.

Comment: share your table index detail as well as query execuation plan

Comment: also why are you sorting?  get rid of order by  , seems like not necessary

Comment: I don't have much columns on those tables. Those are the only columns I need. Eventually I'd like to have this table created every week to see data from the last 7 days only.

Comment: I'm using ORDER BY because one article I read says it will help with optimization and make the query faster.

Comment: I added the columns per tables

Comment: Rows in a table are like balls in a basket.  There is no order to them.  Therefor it makes zero sense to try to 'order by' on an insert.  The only thing that "accomplishes" is to force the driving SELECT to go through the extra work of sorting the the result before inserting them into the table, where the order ceases to exist.  Perhaps that unnecessary sort is a big part of your performance issue.  I'd like to see the citation on the article you refer to.

Comment: I see okay, I can easily remove that then. Any suggestions on the overall query on how I can further optimize it?

Comment: Direct filter on `A.DATE_DT` will perform way much faster than join, because you use `inner join` and do not use other attributes from the calendar table. But the real answer may only be provided if you post the **actual** execution plan, which may be gathered with [`dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL_MONITOR.html#GUID-04851EB0-32AB-424C-91A1-65AD9220A690) with `format => 'ALL ALLSTATS LAST'`

Comment: The way it is written, you are asking Oracle to get all data for all dates first, potentially millions of rows, and then filter for the 7 days you want. Of course, the optimiser may choose the reverse join order starting with `d`, but I wonder (1) why you specified the join backwards, and (2) what the actual join order is in the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to comment on performance without an execution plan. Assuming you have foreign keys in place, the joins to the other tables seem unnecessary. You could try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE PARALLEL 6 as
SELECT 
        A.DATE_DT,
        A.STORE_NUM,
        A.ITEM_ID,
        A.BALANCE_ONHAND,
        A.DEMAND,
        A.PENDING_DELIVERY            
FROM TABLE.QTY A
WHERE A.DATE_DT BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-6) and TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

I suspect if you don't have an index on `DATE_DT`, you'll want one.

You say you're going to be recreating this table every week? It sounds like what you want is a materialized view, not a table. You could just have that refresh every week.